# ssis the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: email, ssis, smtp, exchange-server

i haven't a lot of experience with SSIS. Now i'm trying to send an email From a Microsoft Exchange account "abc@mycompany.com" to the same account "abc@mycompany.com".

I'm using a send mail task , and in the SMTP manage connection i have indicated the smpt.office365.com smtp server.

When i try to excecute the flow i have this error:
      the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM.

I know there are a lot of question about, but i don't find any solution for my case. There is some particular settings to set?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you checked "Enable Secure Socket Layer (SSL)" checkbox in the SMTP Connection Manager Editor of your send mail task?

Comment: Yes and there is the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using a c# script instead of the email smtp task:

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(SendMailFrom, SendMailTo);
            mail.Body = SendMailBody;
            mail.Subject = SendMailSubject;


                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachmentDiscardContratti));


                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachmentDiscardOrdini));


            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailUsername, EmailPassword);
            client.Send(mail);
```